# How can I print this pattern in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript.How can I print this pattern in javascript??

```
        1
      1 0
    1 0 1
  1 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 1
```

My code is this:

```
function drawPattern(){
    for (i=1; i<5; i++) { 

        for (j=1; j<=(5-i); j++) {
            document.write(" ");
        }
        for (var k = 0; k < i; k++) {
            if((i+k)%2!=0){
                document.write("1");
            }
            else{
                document.write("0");
            }

        }
        document.write('</br>')
    }

}
```

Running this code produces no errors, but causes my browser to hang. What am I doing wrong??

Comment: What result are you getting?

Comment: Why is this getting downvotes and close votes????

Comment: WARNING: this code just hanged my browser. So please modify it before running and checking

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir What do you mean why??? It shows no effort whatsoever.  It exemplifies the close reason: "Why isn't this code working?"

Comment: @zero298 _no effort_!!! 70% of the question is code made by OP (code that didn't work obviously).

Comment: @zero298 From the help center: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself." This question includes desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it. This question should remain open, as it follows the question guidelines

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ this isn't something to argue about guys, @Nishant if you want help please tell us what output you're getting

Comment: @mhodges `a specific problem or error` I do not see that in this post

Comment: @mhodges well put.

Comment: I also does not understand why it hanged my browser??There is not any infinite loop in this code

Comment: I'll take OP's defense and notice that the second loop is infinite.. thus he doesn't have a clear error to notice where the mistake may be.

Comment: The question does not tell us what result the OP is getting, or what the specific problem is.  We're just given some code and told it doesn't work.  That is not sufficient.

Comment: @Nishant Your second for loop (with j) is infinite because you are starting at 1 and decrementing j each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

The second loop in your code is infinite, j decrease and thus j is always smaller than 5-i (=4).

Then you will probably need non-breaking space because the browsers tend not to display normal space when they start a line.
To write an unbreakable space use `document.write("&nbsp;");`